# What is the last achievement? And how do I get it?

Tags: horizon-chase

I've finished every single race in Horizon Chase at first place while getting all the tokens, unlocked all three rewards at the end of the game, and got all but one achievement, which is a secret one.

Does anyone know what is this achievement and how to get it?

I tried searching for it on Google but didn't find anything. There are 2 posts on Reddit about this ([here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidGaming/comments/4lad23/whats_the_last_achievement_of_horizon_chase/) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidGaming/comments/4y39ze/does_anyone_know_what_the_last_secret_achievement/)) but one has no answers and the other has no solutions.

Edit: Just finished the Australia Cup (added in the last update) finishing all races in first place while collecting all tokens, and still didn't get the achievement.